# Математическая операция (деление) в скрипте js и её вывод

Tags: javascript, jquery, математика, деление

который выводит в строку товары для передачи данных. В этом скрипте нужно сделать математическую операцию - деление, но не знаю как. Должна выводиться цена за 1 шт. товара, то есть нужно: **p.children[3] (общая сумма)** поделить **p.children[2] (кол-во)** = [цена за шт.]

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
function OrderProducts() {
let orderText = ([...document.querySelectorAll('.t706__product')]
            .map(p => `• ${p.children[1].textContent} ${p.children[2].textContent} шт. = ${p.children[3].textContent} [цена за шт. **здесь**]`))
            .join('\n');
document.querySelector('.order__product').textContent = `${orderText}`;
}
setInterval(OrderProducts, 500);
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Держите, округлил длиные числа до сотых

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  function OrderProducts() {
    let orderText = ([...document.querySelectorAll('.t706__product')]
                .map(p => `• ${p.children[1].textContent} ${p.children[2].textContent} шт. = ${p.children[3].textContent} [цена за шт. ${(p.children[3].textContent / p.children[2].textContent).toFixed(2)}]`))
                .join('\n');
    document.querySelector('.order__product').textContent = `${orderText}`;
  }
  
  setInterval(OrderProducts, 500);
});
```

Comment: Спасибо, но я забыл одну вещь учесть: **p.children[2]** идет со знаком валюты **₽**, можно ли его как то не учитывать при выполнении математической функции? Иначе значение будет неизвестно NaN

Comment: p.children[2].textContent.match(/\d+/g)

Comment: а убрать пробел можно, просто числа типа до 999 делит, т.к в числе пробелов, а числа типа 1 500 не делит из за пробела

Comment: Тогда кусок кода , что выше, замените на это p.children[2].textContent.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '')

Comment: Спасибо большое!)